# Why PHP exe sometimes not return $output?

Tags: php

```
$output = array();
exec($sjis_cmd, $output);
```

I check program: `$sjis_cmd` had finish success.

`$sjis_cmd`: Call Script of Indesign Server and Return Value;
Ex:

```
function main() {
return 1;
}
```

But result $output:

sometimes return ok: 2 parameters

sometimes can't return : `count($output)=0`

Why PHP exe sometimes can't return `$output`?

Comment: The question which screams too me is why are you using exec? And exec could return empty if there was no output. If you're always expecting output.  Check your commands issued. If you're unsure.  Use `var_dump ($output);` and post the response here along with your command (s)

Comment: Perhaps there wasn't any output to return?

Comment: sometimes return ok: 2 parameters: Because i exe indesign server script and return value

Comment: @DT we don't know what we're dealing with unless we see all relevant code to the question

Comment: Show the actual value of `$sjis_cmd`.... but `return` doesn't echo any output, and how are you calling function `main`?

Comment: $sjis_cmd=sampleclient -host localhost:100C:\indtools\InDesignServerScript\LIXIL\test.jsx , only call exec($sjis_cmd, $output); will can exe function main

Answer (score 1):

Because there was no exec output?

Comment: sometimes return ok: 2 parameters: Because i exe indesign server script and return value.

Comment: Case call exec($sjis_cmd, $output) in PHP result count($output)=0, But If i copy $sjis_cmd paste to cmd.exe still return 2 parameters.